# How do C# classes deal with dollar signs in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, google-data-api

I'm getting a JSON feed from [Google's data API](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/json.html) and a lot of the property names start with a $ character (dollar sign).

My problem is that I can't create a C# class with a variable name starting with a dollar sign, it's not allowed by the language. I'm using [JSON.NET from Newtonsoft](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) to convert JSON to C# objects. How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could try using the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to specify the name:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$someName")]
public string SomeName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 19):

firas489 was on the right track that $ indicates metadata, not an actual data field. However the fix is actually to do this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;
```

Set the metadata handling to ignore, and then you can serialize/deserialize the property using the PropertyName attribute:

```
[JsonProperty("$id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Perhaps it has changed since OP posted, but current Json.Net (13.0) requires setting metadata handling to "ignore" to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Those items with the dollar sign ($) are usually meant to be metadata and NOT fields. When JSON.NET serializes an object and you tell it to handle the object types, it will insert $ items that denotes metadata for correct deserialization later on.

If you want to treat the $ items as metadata, use JsonSerializerSettings. For example:

```
Dim jsonSettings As New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings With {.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All}
Dim jsonOut As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects, jsonSettings)
```

The `TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All` tells JSON to handle the datatypes while relying on the $ for information.

Comment: So I have in essence the inverse of this problem? I'm writing a tool to create json schema, and need to output $schema, $id, #ref and the like. I'm struggling with a good way to approach that, the current thought is to potentially have something that runs post that will replace 'id' with '$id' but feels kludgy. Happy to place this in a new question if need be.