# Can not deserialize JSON containing $ref keys

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following code trying to deserialize a JSON string and the library gives me this error:

> Additional content found in JSON reference object. A JSON reference object should only have a $ref property. Path 'user.obj', line 1, position 34.

Any idea what is wrong?  (I understand that it is complaining about the second $ref, but I don't know why.)  What is the workaround ?

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = "{\"user\": {\"$ref\": \"123456\", \"obj\": {\"$ref\": \"123456\"}}}";
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(s).Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("user")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("$ref")]
    public string Ref { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyAttribute("obj")]
    public Obj Obj { get; set; }
}

public class Obj
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("$ref")]
    public string Ref { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Json.Net uses `$ref` along with `$id` as metadata to preserve object references in JSON. So when it sees `$ref` it assumes that property is not part of the actual JSON property set, but an internal identifier referring to a matching `$id` somewhere else in the JSON.  Since your usage of `$ref` is different than what Json.Net expects to see, it is throwing an error.

**UPDATE**

In Json.Net version [6.0.4](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/6.0.4) and later, there is now a setting by which you can instruct the deserializer to treat these metadata properties as normal properties instead of consuming them.  All you need to do is set the `MetadataPropertyHandling` setting to `Ignore` and then deserialize as usual.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FormDefinitionList>(json, settings);
```

Prior to version 6.0.4, a workaround was needed to solve this issue.  If you cannot upgrade to the lastest version of Json.Net, see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20698098/10263) for some possible solutions.

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks for the answer. I have unfortunately no control over the format. I already had replace the '$' with string replace and it hopefully work. I will try to investigate the custom Json Converter (just to level up my json.net knowldge)

Comment: **Lifesaver.** It took two days to find this.