# C#: Deserialize JSON with $ref paths in json-schema style

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON files that reference others using the reference type used by json-schema and swagger. Below is a summary of these ref format.

I've searched quite a bit and didn't find a library in C# that allows me to resolve to deserialize json that has these reference style.

Any clues on how to do this, ideally using JSON.NET?

Ref format:

- Local Reference – **$ref: '#/definitions/myElement'** # means go to the root of the current document and then find elements definitions and myElement one after one.
- Remote Reference – **$ref: 'document.json'** Uses the whole document located on the same server and in the same location.

  - The element of the document located on the same server – **$ref: 'document.json#/myElement'**
  - The element of the document located in the parent folder – **$ref: '../document.json#/myElement'**
  - The element of the document located in another folder – **$ref: '../another-folder/document.json#/myElement'**
- URL Reference – **$ref: 'http://path/to/your/resource'** Uses the whole document located on the different server.

  - The specific element of the document stored on the different server – **$ref: 'http://path/to/your/resource.json#myElement'**
  - The document on the different server, which uses the same protocol (for example, HTTP or HTTPS) – **$ref: '//anotherserver.com/files/example.json'**

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299390/can-not-deserialize-json-containing-ref-keys