# Deserializing json-schema with C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm developing my own JSON-to-POCO framework.
The way I'm doing it is, that I created the class of a Json-schema that looks like this:

```
public class JsonSchema  
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, JsonSchema> properties { get; set; }
    public JsonSchema items { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<string> required { get; set; }
    public bool ispartial = true; 
}
```

and deserializing the schema to have my object(s) so I can work with it perfectly.

Everything is working fine for now, I'm getting my generated C#-file. But only if I don't add `$ref`s to my json. (Since it's much less code to add a reference in json instead of copy-paste the classes I want to support them)

What I need to do is, adding the `$ref` to my class. Problem here is, I cannot add an attribute like

```
public string $ref { get; set; }
```

to my code.

Any idea what I could do?

> The problem was also, that you cannot deserialize $id and $ref with default settings. This was solved by reading this nice post here: [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<> (string) returns null value for $id property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686336/jsonconvert-deserializeobject-string-returns-null-value-for-id-property)

Comment: If you are using Json.net you can add a [JsonProperty("$ref")] and rename the actual property to something like reference.

Comment: @riteshmeher 
it's working fine with $schema when I tested it. Not with my $ref. So this has to be another part of my code where the mistake is. Post it as an answere so I can mark it as correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add [JsonProperty] attribute to the property you want to change the name.

```
[JsonProperty("$ref")]
public string reference { get; set; }
```