# Deserialize Json with json properties having special characters Restsharp

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization, restsharp

I have following json (a part from large json response) returned by google contacts api v3

```
"entry": [
   {
    "id": {
     "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/zahidmadeel%40gmail.com/base/a769270d0bdc93"
    },
    "gd$etag": "\"R38-fDVSLit7I2A9WhFbEUkNQw0.\"",
    "updated": {
     "$t": "2013-09-02T18:44:56.154Z"
    },
    "app$edited": {
     "xmlns$app": "http://www.w3.org/2007/app",
     "$t": "2013-09-02T18:44:56.154Z"
    },
    "category": [
     {
      "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
      "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
     }
    ],
    "title": {
     "$t": "Ruairi Browne"
    },
    "link": [
     {
      "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo",
      "type": "image/*",
      "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/zahidmadeel%40gmail.com/a769270d0bdc93?v=3.0"
     },
     {
      "rel": "self",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/zahidmadeel%40gmail.com/thin/a769270d0bdc93?v=3.0"
     },
     {
      "rel": "edit",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/zahidmadeel%40gmail.com/thin/a769270d0bdc93?v=3.0"
     }
    ],
    "gd$name": {
     "gd$fullName": {
      "$t": "Ruairi Browne"
     },
     "gd$givenName": {
      "$t": "Ruairi"
     },
     "gd$familyName": {
      "$t": "Browne"
     }
    },
    "gd$email": [
     {
      "address": "ruairi.browne@mhlabs.net",
      "primary": "true",
      "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other"
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "id": {
     "$t": "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/zahidmadeel%40gmail.com/base/e268ff0bc63d0b"
    },
    "gd$etag": "\"QH89ezVSLyt7I2A9Wx5VE0gOTgY.\"",
    "updated": {
     "$t": "2010-10-06T08:48:41.163Z"
    },
    "app$edited": {
     "xmlns$app": "http://www.w3.org/2007/app",
     "$t": "2010-10-06T08:48:41.163Z"
    },
    "category": [
     {
      "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind",
      "term": "http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"
     }
    ],
    "title": {
     "$t": ""
    },
    "link": [
     {
      "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo",
      "type": "image/*",
      "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/zahidmadeel%40gmail.com/e268ff0bc63d0b?v=3.0"
     },
     {
      "rel": "self",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/zahidmadeel%40gmail.com/thin/e268ff0bc63d0b?v=3.0"
     },
     {
      "rel": "edit",
      "type": "application/atom+xml",
      "href": "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/zahidmadeel%40gmail.com/thin/e268ff0bc63d0b?v=3.0"
     }
    ],
    "gd$email": [
     {
      "address": "salah@cirinpharma.com",
      "primary": "true",
      "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other"
     }
    ]
   }]
```

and I have created following classes so that this response could be deserialized in .NET objects

```
public class Entry
    {

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public  Id Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gd$etag")]
        public string GdEtag { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("updated")]
        public  Updated Updated { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gd$name")]
        public GdName GdName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gd$email")]
        public List<GdEmail> GdEmail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gContact$website")]
        public List<GContactWebsite> GContactWebsite { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gContact$groupMembershipInfo")]
        public List<GContactGroupMembershipInfo> GContactGroupMembershipInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Feed
    {

        [JsonProperty("xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("xmlns$openSearch")]
        public string XmlnsOpenSearch { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("xmlns$gContact")]
        public string XmlnsGContact { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("xmlns$batch")]
        public string XmlnsBatch { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("xmlns$gd")]
        public string XmlnsGd { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gd$etag")]
        public string GdEtag { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public Id Id { get; set; }



        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public Title Title { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("author")]
        public List<Author> Author { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("generator")]
        public Generator Generator { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("openSearch$totalResults")]
        public OpenSearchTotalResults OpenSearchTotalResults { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("openSearch$startIndex")]
        public OpenSearchStartIndex OpenSearchStartIndex { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("openSearch$itemsPerPage")]
        public OpenSearchItemsPerPage OpenSearchItemsPerPage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("entry")]
        public List<Entry> Entry { get; set; }
    }

    public class GoogleContactModel
    {

        [JsonProperty("version")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("encoding")]
        public string Encoding { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("feed")]
        public Feed Feed { get; set; }
    }
```

but the data is not properly de-serialized into c# objects. The problem arises whenever there is `$` in json property name. Although, I have decorated each property with `JsonProperty` attribute accordingly, but still json properties with `$` are not converted to relevant data in .NET objects. How can I accomplish this?
**EDIT**
I am not deserializing response myself. I am using rest sharp to make api calls and response is deserialized by restsharp on the following line of code

```
response = restClient.Execute<GoogleContactModel>(restRequest);
```

and I believe rest sharp uses Json.NET on the backend for serialization/deserialization

**Edit2** I just googled a bit and found that restsharp does not use Json.NET for serialization/deseirialization. And it has its own attribute called `DeserializeAs` as equivalent to `JsonProperty` in Json.Net. I replaced all `JsonProperty` attributes with `DeserializeAs` attributes but it still does not work.

Comment: This answer indicates setting `MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore` on your `JsonSerializerSettings ` will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32483891/535515

Comment: If your question is not related to Json.Net, I suggest removing the `json.net` tag; otherwise you'll get people giving you answers for that library (and/or closing this question as a duplicate of the one @Gus mentioned, which I almost did), adding the `restsharp` tag, and removing it from the title.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @MikeMcCaughan. Just did that