# Deserialization not working with a property $type, why?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have an JSON which contains a property that starts with $ sign.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var my_jsondata = @"{ '$type': 'Psd' }";

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassToDeserialize>(my_jsondata);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Type);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

I want to deserialize this json to my class:

```
public class ClassToDeserialize
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$type", Order = -2)]
    public Constants.Party? Type { get; set; }

    
}
```

And here is my enum

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum Party
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "Psd")]
        Psd,
        [EnumMember(Value = "Pnl")]
        Pnl
    }
```

My problem is with that $type sign because if I change it everything works fine by deserialization but if it stays than the mapping does not take place.
Now result.Type will be null and nothing appears in Console. Could you please help me.

Comment: What is `, Order = -2`?

Comment: We use Order = -2 so that this will be the first property do be deserialized.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works"? Error? Also, note that the single quote for strings is not valid in JSON as per spec.

Comment: It does not appear any error but the mapping is not working. I saw just now, the problem is with $type and not only with $ sign. If I am using any other name (ex $anotherName) it works perfectly

Comment: I added a minimal reproductible example as an answer so it can be better viewed

Comment: Why does it contain `$type`, can you change that name? By default, JSON.NET uses that property to encode information about your CLR types used for (de)serialization.

Comment: Please edit your question, don't post an answer with additional info

Comment: I cannot change $type. So looks the request that I am receving.

Comment: That seems a little naughty. `$type` should be perfectly valid JSON so it's a little cryptic that JSON.Net introduces arbitrary constraints like that.

Comment: Looks like you just need to turn off [metadata handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32483891/542251)

Comment: You should be able to accept the duplicate if it answers your question @PetriAdrian